# How can I edit a layer mask like a normal layer in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, mask

I want to just edit it as a black-and-white image, like any normal layer.

Answer (score 1):

Click the **Layer Mask** on the **Layers Panel**, then turn **off** the *visibility* of the other channels in the **Channels Panel** by clicking the eye icon next to the [RGB] (or [CMYK]) channel.

[image]

You can then highlight the mask channel and edit it like a greyscale image layer.

(This is really what Option/Alt-clicking the mask thumbnail does)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer; Alt-clicking the layer mask opens it for editing. (This is seriously awful UI design.)

Comment: Answer is correct. Opinion is opinion & others may not agree. FYI, shift-click toggles its visibility too. If you can figure out a simpler method to accessing 3 levels of functionality with a single click, I'm sure Adobe would be happy to hear it.

Comment: You can edit the layer mask by simply selecting the layer mask thumbnail, and then you can paint on it directly - although by default the layer mask is not visible - it's still fully editable without toggling visibility.

Comment: @Tetsujin There should be an ”Edit” option in the context menu of the mask. This is the place people look for options. Alt-clicking is arbitrary and cannot be used unless you know it beforehand.